# Loop for variable names in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to do a loop in the following way:

```
for(i in 1:38){
        brdf$g[[i]]<-ifelse(brdf$C[[i]]==4,brdf$P[[i]],0) 
        brdf$g[[i]]<-max(brdf$g_[[i]])
        }
```

In the data frame `brdf`, I already have `C1, C2...,C38` and `P1, P2...,P38`. Now I want to create variables `g1, g2,...g38` so that `g1=P1` if `C1==4`, `g2=P2` if `C2==4`  ,...`g38=P38` if `C38==4`.

When i try to run the code above the error is:

```
Error in g_[i] <- ifelse(brdf$C[i] == 4, brdf$P[i], 0) : 
  replacement has length zero
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Creating variables iteratively is usually unadvised (cluttering of the environment / potential instability?). Perhaps you meant to append values to an existing vector? You can do so via: `g <- c(g, new_value)`. If you're dealing with a lot of data, pre-allocating the vector before the for loop might be beneficial.

Comment: Replace your single square brackets by double brackets

Comment: Solve the error, but the variables were not created in the data frame

Comment: it only apperas g_ in data, with values of "logic()". Is there a better way that can i loop this?

Comment: Can you post an example of your data? Just a toy example would suffice, with what's expected.

Comment: here is more clear what i need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330494/gen-variable-conditional-on-other-variables-from-a-different-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment93541343_53330494